# Append date from another table without joining

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in oracle that has data for different years.

Table 1: This has data for years 2016 - 2018. This is a static table ie wont be refreshed again.
Table 2: This table has data for years >= 2019. This table is being refreshed 3 times a week and has a column REFRESH_DATE that contains the last refreshed date.

Now I have to do a union of table 1 and table 2 but since table 1 is static how do I take table 2's refresh date to table 1?

For example 1) Current Scenario:

```
with tABLE_1 as

( select  '99WC2008' as pol_id, to_date( '1/23/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '-1' as Model from dual Union all
select  '96WC2003' as pol_id,  to_date('1/22/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.34' as Model from dual Union all
select  '90WC2003' as pol_id,  to_date('1/21/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.55' as Model from dual Union all
select  '10XYZ23' as pol_id,  to_date('1/12/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0' as Model from dual Union all
select  '09XYZ23' as pol_id,  to_date('1/11/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0.3' as Model from dual)
,
TABLE_2 AS

( select  'XWG5564' as pol_id, to_date( '1/23/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '-1' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
select  'TTFG556' as pol_id,  to_date('1/22/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.34' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
select  'TTH676Y' as pol_id,  to_date('1/21/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.55' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
Select  'DFE5756' as pol_id,  to_date('2/01/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
select  '567HNG6' as pol_id,  to_date('2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0.3' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual)

SELECT * FROM 
(
select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model  from TABLE_1
UNION ALL
select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model  from TABLE_2
)
ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC

2) Required_output: Always taking the Refresh date from Table_2 and display it in Table_1 as well.

    with tABLE_1 as
    
    ( select  '99WC2008' as pol_id, to_date( '1/23/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '-1' as Model from dual Union all
    select  '96WC2003' as pol_id,  to_date('1/22/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.34' as Model from dual Union all
    select  '90WC2003' as pol_id,  to_date('1/21/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.55' as Model from dual Union all
    select  '10XYZ23' as pol_id,  to_date('1/12/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0' as Model from dual Union all
    select  '09XYZ23' as pol_id,  to_date('1/11/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0.3' as Model from dual)
    ,
    TABLE_2 AS
    
    ( select  'XWG5564' as pol_id, to_date( '1/23/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '-1' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
    select  'TTFG556' as pol_id,  to_date('1/22/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.34' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
    select  'TTH676Y' as pol_id,  to_date('1/21/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'RETAIL' as industry , '0.55' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
    Select  'DFE5756' as pol_id,  to_date('2/01/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual Union all
    select  '567HNG6' as pol_id,  to_date('2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as Eff_dt , 'TECH' as industry , '0.3' as Model, to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from dual)
    
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model ,  to_date( '2/08/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') as REFRESH_DATE from TABLE_1
    UNION ALL
    select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model ,REFRESH_DATE  from TABLE_2
    )
    ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC
```

Is it possible to get data from another table without joining? In the above Union step i am hardcoding the date for table_1, the requirement is to automatically pull that date from table_2.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your sample data... isn't. Are you saying all columns in table 2 have the same `refresh_date` value, so all rows are updated three times a week, even if it's just to update that date? That would seem a bit odd and redundant (but you could mirror that value for table 1 data without a join). If they have different dates then which one would you apply to each row in table 1 - is there some connection between them? Please edit your question to have a [mcve] and explanation of your logic..

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for the sample data; and a complete description of the problem, including details of how you want to pick the refresh date from table2 to apply to table1. For example, if table2 has 10 rows do you want to cross join the tables and have all 10 refresh dates for each row in table 1 or do you want the maximum, minimum or something else?

Comment: Apologies for not editing it properly. I have provided sample data now (Current and Expected). 
To address the comments:
Yes, all rows in table 2 have same refresh_Date. Its to be interpreted as data refresh date.
The final table(after Union is to be used by a Reporting tool) and 
the reporting team is asking that this table show some sort of Refresh date to 
be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the `REFRESH_DATE`s are identical, you can use:

```sql
SELECT pol_id,
       Eff_dt,
       industry,
       model,
       (SELECT REFRESH_DATE FROM table_2 WHERE ROWNUM = 1) as REFRESH_DATE
from   TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT pol_id,
       Eff_dt,
       industry,
       model,
       REFRESH_DATE
from   TABLE_2
ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC
```

Alternatively, you could use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` or `MAX(refresh_date)`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=257cf7df3ea24a0b3ef661cb29f0193f)*

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get a null refresh date from table 1 branch of the union, as a placeholder; and then in the outer query, use an analytic `max()`:

```
max(refresh_date) over ()
```

... to get the highest value across that combined data set - i.e., the date from the table 2 rows.

```
SELECT pol_id, eff_dt, industry, model,
  max(refresh_date) over () as refresh_date
FROM 
(
  select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model, null as refresh_date from TABLE_1
  UNION ALL
  select pol_id,  Eff_dt, industry, model, refresh_date from TABLE_2
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=362a2691fde0085936834eb271f10230)

You probably won't gain any real advantage from not hitting table 2 a second time, since you're already retrieving all the data from it; and any gain could be outweighed by the cost of the analytic call. You might still find one approach is marginally faster than the other - I suspect you'd have to look quite hard to notice though.